# Benefits of using a sine wave filter with variable frequency drive

Tags: motor, filter, induction-motor, sine, vfd

Sometimes sine wave filters are installed on the output side of a variable frequency drive (VFD.) My understanding is that these filters are advised in situations where there may be capacitance among the wires in the cable going to the motor. The idea, if I understand correctly, is that the sine wave filter smoothes the output, eliminating the spikes at the edges of the PWM pulses.

I'm installing a variable frequency drive in a setting where I have a very well insulated short length of cable. The specifications in the VFD manual do not suggest I am close to needing a sine wave filter.

I happen to have come into possession of a sine wave filter that is appropriately sized for the current. I'm thinking that using it may be gentler on the motor. My intuition is that the voltage spikes may be damaging to the insulation on the motor, and the unfiltered PWM sine-like output of the VFD may cause the motor to run rougher, thus wearing it out.

Are my intuitions about protecting the motor correct? Is it a good idea to use the sine wave filter?

EDIT:
Because the answers below are conditioned details of the application, I'm adding some info. This is for my own farm, there is no client. I suspect I could sell the sine wave filter for 150 bucks on eBay. The motor being driven is a 240V 3ph 5HP submersible motor turning a well pump. The cable is xhhw-2 12AWG submersible cable (made by Lütze I think.) The total length of cable from the enclosure to the well pump is about 25 m.

Comment: Charles will be along shortly to answer your question ...

Comment: *"...that the voltage spikes may be damaging to the insulation on the motor..."*. Are you referring to the enamel on the wire? What insulation?

Comment: I've heard that the voltage spikes can damage the insulation on the windings of the motor. I don't know if this is true.

Comment: it is true ....

Comment: Do you know the parameters of the filter?

Comment: Seems to me the sine filter will probably make the motor quieter if that is an issue. Most VFD's use a carrier frequency in the audible range, and this causes the stator to ring or hum. If you have ever used a VFD you probably know what I am talking about. I suspect that the sine wave filter will greatly attenuate the carrier (PWM frequency).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sine filter is very expensive and bulky part of the drive. Without a choke and a shielded cable the VFD will work nice upto 35m, with unshielded cable even more. Then you add a choke. Lastly, when cables extend more than 200m a sine filter is employed.

There is a substantial voltage drop on the filter, so the motor will lose power. There is a 10% voltage drop on the filter and a V/f characteristics has to be adapted to reach a 100% voltage on lower frequency than nominal.

EDIT:

If this is for your own use, then use the filter if you have nowhere to resell it. If you want to make a quality machine, then use a choke. If you already fixed the price for the machine, then install nothing. From my experience the customer wants to buy as cheap as possible, just few of them do demand chokes to be already present.

It is true that bearings do wear faster without a choke/filter.

EDIT:

Keep the filter.

- It will protect the VFD against the motor short circuit, since the current rise will be limited and the protection will trip at a safe moment.  The submerged cable will deteriorate through time, so you are about to expect a SC failure over time.
- It will lower the EMI if plan to use unshielded cable
- It's way more expensive than you think

Don't know about the cable, but it seems not for water.

Comment: The bearings wear out due to VFD induced voltages along the rotor shaft. These induce circulating currents through the bearings and back around through the machine frame. My understanding is that it becomes a problem after a certain cable length. It can be mitigated by using the right cable and/or using insulated bearings at one end of the motor to break the loop.

Comment: What does "choke" mean in this context? Is that another word for a dVdt filter?

Comment: @AndrewCone Exactly. You can google: vfd choke.

Comment: The filter will reduce the probability of risk to partial discharge induced short-circuit failures overtime

Comment: "just use it" could cause other problems because the use-case it not stated. What is the pole-pair of the motor, what is the mechanical speed, what is the switching freq, what is natural Freq of the filter. Sure if you have it and have space to  spare why not but if the two Freq too close together the filter could be shunting a lot more current than it should

Comment: @JonRB These are standard filters for VFD use, they are built for specific VFD power, switching frequency and fundamental freq. up to. When you buy it, you get the manual.

Comment: "standard filters" only work for "standard usecases". I have seen enough smoldering drives to ask the question. My stand drives have in excess of 600hz electrical frequency while only producing 6000rpm shaft velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Whether to use a sine filter, or any filter is highly dependant on whether there are EMI concerns or insulation concerns.

The high dv/dt of the leading edge of voltage waveforms from variable speed electric motor drives can lead to motor bearing failure, motor winding short circuits, and EMI compliance challenges.Passive output filters are used to mitigate the negative effects of fast rising edges generated by PWM inverters. These result in high peak voltages and high frequency ringing at the motor terminals.

There are three options

1. No filter.  This is obviously the cheapest, lightest and requires the least effort
2. d/dt filter. This attempts to mitigate the unmatched impedance via slowing down the leading edge. Three topologies exist: RC at the motor, RL at the drive, RLC at the drive.
3. Sine filter. This suppresses "all" higher frequency transients leaving the underlying sinus drive signal being present. With a high enough separation between switching frequency and drive fundamental, the L-C components can be electrically "small" but with higher current levels they inevitably end up being physically large.

When you need to use an output filter and the type of filter is dependent on the length of cable, the characteristics of the cable and whether there are multiple independent loads attached to the output.

If the inverter is to serve as a locally generated AC grid and there are several independent loads (eg multiple induction machines), then a "clean" sinusoidal output is required.  If the output cable length is excessive and/or no overbraid then a sinefilter might be required to manage the EMI response.

If the distance between the motor and the drive is "short", there is an argument that no output filter is needed at all.

What if the distance between the drive is too long for no filter but too short to warrant a sine-filter?  that is when the d/dt filters are used but what governs the "distance" that such filters are used?  its very dependant on the characteristic impedance of the cable, the terminating impedance of the motor and the risetime of the output switches.  For IGBT based inverter this distance that can be used without any filter is ~ 25m but SiC MOSFET based inverters this distance collapses to 5m. Because of the rise-time and flight-time there is the potential for a 2PU overshoot at the motor terminals as well as high frequency oscillation.

NEMA MG 1-2016 standard and the IEC 60034-25 standard set recommended limits on the rise time of the voltage waveform and the peak voltages allowed

Below is an example of a simulation of a SiC drive and a 8AWG harness
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the VFD manufacturer has provided advice about output filtering, that should be your primary advice. That will be based on their specific VFD design and its built-in motor protection features. The use of a 240 volt motor should provide a lot of safety margin for the winding insulation. Winding insulation is usually rated for 480 volt or even 600 volt operation. It the motor is reconnectable for 480 volt operation the insulation will certainly be rated for 480 volts. It is best to use a motor that is advertised by the manufacturer as suitable for VFD duty. However many manufacturers design all of their motors to meet the minimum requirements for VFD operation.

Bearing currents problems are difficult to predict and prevent. They are caused by currents that flow through capacitive coupling between the motor stator windings and the motor rotor and from the rotor through the bearings to the motor frame and ground. You may want to see what the motor manufacturer's literature says about that. You may also want to see what the manufacturer of the sine wave filter claims as benefits provided by that product.

Comment: Good man. I knew you'd show up. +1.

Comment: Charles, can you check my comment below Marcus' answer. You're blaming capacitive coupling and current through the bearings to ground. I had picked up on a brief training seminar that there was an axial current through the rotors circulating through the bearings and around through the frame. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Transistor, I would not be surprised to find competing theories about bearing currents. Here is a document that says that there are several ways in which the currents are generated, several current paths and several remediation techniques. There is no mention of sine filters on the output. https://library.e.abb.com/public/8c253c2417ed0238c125788f003cca8e/ABB_Technical_guide_No5_RevC.pdf

Comment: Here is another opinion: https://www.yaskawa.com/delegate/getAttachment?documentId=AN.AFD.17&cmd=documents&documentName=AN.AFD.17.pdf